# yarn: command not found after gatsby deployment to netlify

Tags: gatsby, yarnpkg, netlify

I keep getting this error.

```
Executing user command: yarn build
/usr/local/bin/build: line 112: yarn: command not found
```

I read from [Netlify - Manage build dependencies](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#npm) that `yarn` must be included in my `package.json`. Yet I see `yarn` mentioned in my `package.json`

I've cleaned the cached and deployed again. I tried adding yarn and npm version as a build environment but it still doesn't work. I also looked into [How to change your default package manager for your next project?](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-cli/#how-to-change-your-default-package-manager-for-your-next-project) but didn't find a json with the following structure:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "yarn"
  }
}
```

FWIW this builds fine *locally*. It only errors after I push to my remote repo and Netlify is building. What makes this even more weird is that this error doesn't happen if I use the *default* starter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit counter intuitive, but all I needed to do was add an empty `yarn.lock` file to the root directory and push it to my repo. The error message went away immediately!

From [Netlify - Manage build dependencies](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#npm)

> ⚠️ yarn needs a `yarn.lock`
>
> If any of your build scripts start with yarn, you must have a
>   `yarn.lock` file.
>
> Netlify's buildbot will not install Yarn without it.